# iterator in strut 2.0

Tags: struts2, iterator

I used iterator in my strut application like

s:iterator value="resultList" id="resultData" status="stat" >
s:hidden name="orderItemsList[%{index}].totalCostPrice" id="%{#costPriceId}"          value="%{#resultData.totalCostPrice}"/>
/s:iterator>

here,I got an error when its found totalCostPrice value 0(Zero).

Comment: Sadly the internets have eaten your code example...use the code sample macro or HTML entitles for your < (&lt;) and > (&gt;) characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s:iterator value="roleList" status="roleList">
s:property value="name" />
s:property value="description" />
/s:iterator>